# Перенос слова с мягким знаком со стоящей перед ним согласной буквой

Tags: перенос

**Правило**: Мягкий знак означает мягкость согласного звука. При переносе слова нельзя отделять мягкий знак от стоящей перед ним согласной буквы. **Пример**: *учитель- ница, школь- ница*.

Можно так перенести: *учите- льница, шко- льница*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, конечно, предпочтительным считается перенос по слогам, которые "легче"  разбивают слово с точки зрения артикуляции. ***У- чи- тель- ни- ца*** (понятно, что по правилам нельзя оставить одну букву в конце строки).

Некоторые строгие правила переноса в настоящее время могут носить рекомендательный характер и допускать другие варианты (см. [**Правила переносов**](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/141-perenos), комментарии редакции портала).

На Грамоте.ру есть объяснение со словом ***бульон***, при переносе которого возможен такой вариант: ***бу- льон*** (см. [**Вопрос № 265293**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=perenos)).

Так что на Ваш вопрос можно ответить положительно. Такие варианты переноса допустимы.

Comment: спасибо за ответ.